# Can't boot into Ubuntu after upgrade from Ubuntu 11 to 12.04 on dual boot system

Tags: 12.04, grub2, windows, wubi

Running Dell Inspiron 15r notebook with Windows 7 Pro and 11.10 Ubuntu (also have Windows CR).  All worked fine until attempted upgrade to 12.04 system which 'locked'.

Via Windows, uninstalled and reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04.  Windows install part went okay, but when rebooted to continue installation in 12.04 was only able to boot into grub (i.e., `grub>` prompt).

Have tried to uninstall and reinstall (via Windows).  Also, ran Boot-Repair CD -- no change.

Here is the [link to the Boot-Repair's Boot Info Summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1010120/):

```
            Boot Info Script 0.61-git-patched      [23 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Syslinux MBR (3.61-4.03) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Dell Utility: FAT16
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /DELLBIO.BIN /DELLRMK.BIN /COMMAND.COM

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /wubildr

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe 
                       /wubildr /wubildr.mbr

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows XP: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda5 starts 
                       at sector 63.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows XP: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda6 starts 
                       at sector 63.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /ubuntu/winboot/wubildr /ubuntu/winboot/wubildr.mbr 
                       /ubuntu/disks/root.disk /ubuntu/disks/swap.disk

sda6/Wubi: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows XP: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda7 starts 
                       at sector 63.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda8 starts 
                       at sector 63.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda9: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda9 starts 
                       at sector 319. But according to the info from fdisk, 
                       sda9 starts at sector 1188757504.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders, total 1250263728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1               2,048       206,847       204,800  de Dell Utility
/dev/sda2             206,848    30,926,847    30,720,000   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3    *     30,926,848   274,791,824   243,864,977   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda4         274,791,825 1,250,256,895   975,465,071   f W95 Extended (LBA)
/dev/sda5         274,791,888   635,852,699   361,060,812   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda6         635,852,763   738,251,009   102,398,247   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda7         738,251,073 1,137,642,974   399,391,902   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda8       1,137,643,038 1,188,745,739    51,102,702   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda9       1,188,757,504 1,250,256,895    61,499,392   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        3030-3030                              vfat       DELLUTILITY
/dev/sda2        CC70378A703779F2                       ntfs       Recovery
/dev/sda3        AC7C4EC27C4E86D4                       ntfs       Rover1-116GB-C
/dev/sda5        01CC9A6FD6FEEC60                       ntfs       Rover1-176GB-D
/dev/sda6        01CC9A6FD8722B70                       ntfs       Rover1-50GB-E-Ubuntu
/dev/sda7        01CC9A6FD9D739B0                       ntfs       Rover1-190GB-F
/dev/sda8        6AD05CC5D05C9961                       ntfs       Rover1-25GB-W7U-32
/dev/sda9        84A8A0EDA8A0DF44                       ntfs       Rover1-30GB-Win8-Preview

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sr0         /live/image              iso9660    (ro,noatime)


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda4

00000000  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
*
000001b0  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 fe  |................|
000001c0  ff ff 07 fe ff ff 3f 00  00 00 cc 59 85 15 00 fe  |......?....Y....|
000001d0  ff ff 05 fe ff ff 0b 5a  85 15 66 79 1a 06 00 00  |.......Z..fy....|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200

Unknown BootLoader on sda6/Wubi

00000000  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  |0000000000000000|
*
00000200


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

  No volume groups found
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 2012-05-27__14h40 ===================
boot-repair version : 3.18-0ppa13~lucid
boot-sav version : 3.18-0ppa29~lucid
/usr/share/boot-sav/gui-g2slaunch.sh: line 91: hash: glade2script: not found
glade2script-gtk2 version : 0.0.1-0ppa4~lucid
internet: no-internet
internet: no-internet
No volume groups found
boot-repair is executed in live-session (Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.3 (squeeze) , squeeze , Debian , i686)

=================== OSPROBER:
/dev/sda2:Windows 7 (loader):Windows:chain
/dev/sda3:Windows 7 (loader):Windows1:chain
/dev/sda8:Windows 7 (loader):Windows2:chain
/dev/sda9:Windows 7 (loader):Windows3:chain

=================== BLKID:
/dev/sda1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="DELLUTILITY" UUID="3030-3030" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="CC70378A703779F2" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Rover1-116GB-C" UUID="AC7C4EC27C4E86D4" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="Rover1-176GB-D" UUID="01CC9A6FD6FEEC60" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda6: LABEL="Rover1-50GB-E-Ubuntu" UUID="01CC9A6FD8722B70" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda7: LABEL="Rover1-190GB-F" UUID="01CC9A6FD9D739B0" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda8: LABEL="Rover1-25GB-W7U-32" UUID="6AD05CC5D05C9961" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda9: LABEL="Rover1-30GB-Win8-Preview" UUID="84A8A0EDA8A0DF44" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"


1 disks with OS, 4 OS : 0 Linux, 0 MacOS, 4 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.

There is Wubi inside sda6

=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:
sda1    : sda,  maybesepboot,   no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    no-os,  not-on-gpt-disk,    part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    no-grldr,   no-b-bcd,   nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  /mnt/boot-sav/sda1.
sda2    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    is-os,  not-on-gpt-disk,    part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    no-grldr,   Boot/BCD,   nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  /mnt/boot-sav/sda2.
sda3    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    is-os,  not-on-gpt-disk,    part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    no-grldr,   Boot/BCD,   nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  /mnt/boot-sav/sda3.
sda5    : sda,  maybesepboot,   no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    no-os,  not-on-gpt-disk,    part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    no-grldr,   no-b-bcd,   nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  /mnt/boot-sav/sda5.
sda6    : sda,  maybesepboot,   no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    no-os,  not-on-gpt-disk,    part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    no-grldr,   no-b-bcd,   nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  /mnt/boot-sav/sda6.
sda7    : sda,  maybesepboot,   no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    no-os,  not-on-gpt-disk,    part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    no-grldr,   no-b-bcd,   nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  /mnt/boot-sav/sda7.
sda8    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    is-os,  not-on-gpt-disk,    part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    no-grldr,   Boot/BCD,   nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  /mnt/boot-sav/sda8.
sda9    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    is-os,  not-on-gpt-disk,    part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    no-grldr,   Boot/BCD,   nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  /mnt/boot-sav/sda9.

sda : MSDos,    not-GPT,    BIOSboot-not-needed,    has-no-EFIpart,     2048 sectors * 512 bytes

=================== PARTED:

Model: ATA TOSHIBA MK6475GS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 640GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
1      1049kB  106MB   105MB   primary   fat16        diag
2      106MB   15.8GB  15.7GB  primary   ntfs         boot
3      15.8GB  141GB   125GB   primary   ntfs
4      141GB   640GB   499GB   extended               lba
5      141GB   326GB   185GB   logical   ntfs
6      326GB   378GB   52.4GB  logical   ntfs
7      378GB   582GB   204GB   logical   ntfs
8      582GB   609GB   26.2GB  logical   ntfs
9      609GB   640GB   31.5GB  logical   ntfs




Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.


Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label


=================== MOUNT:
aufs on / type aufs (rw)
tmpfs on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/sr0 on /live/image type iso9660 (ro,noatime)
tmpfs on /live/cow type tmpfs (rw,noatime,mode=755)
tmpfs on /live type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 type vfat (rw)
/dev/sda2 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 type fuseblk (rw,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda3 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda3 type fuseblk (rw,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda5 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda5 type fuseblk (rw,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda6 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda6 type fuseblk (rw,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda7 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda7 type fuseblk (rw,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda8 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda8 type fuseblk (rw,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda9 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda9 type fuseblk (rw,allow_other,blksize=4096)


/sys/block/sda:  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 sda7 sda8 sda9 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sr0:  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/dev:  block bsg btrfs-control bus cdrom cdrw char console core cpu_dma_latency disk dvd dvdrw fd full fuse hidraw0 hidraw1 hidraw2 hpet initctl input kmsg log MAKEDEV md mem net network_latency network_throughput null port ppp psaux ptmx pts random rfkill rtc rtc0 scd0 sda sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 sda7 sda8 sda9 sg0 sg1 shm snapshot snd sndstat sr0 stderr stdin stdout urandom usb v4l vga_arbiter video0 xconsole zero

=================== DF:

Filesystem    Type    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
aufs          aufs    1.7G  8.2M  1.7G   1% /
tmpfs        tmpfs    1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /lib/init/rw
udev         tmpfs    1.7G  208K  1.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs        tmpfs    1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sr0   iso9660    340M  340M     0 100% /live/image
tmpfs        tmpfs    1.7G  8.2M  1.7G   1% /live/cow
tmpfs        tmpfs    1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /live
tmpfs        tmpfs    1.7G  8.0K  1.7G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1     vfat    100M  120K  100M   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2  fuseblk     15G   14G  1.3G  92% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda3  fuseblk    117G   87G   30G  75% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sda5  fuseblk    173G  151G   23G  88% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
/dev/sda6  fuseblk     49G   40G  9.8G  80% /mnt/boot-sav/sda6
/dev/sda7  fuseblk    191G   84G  107G  44% /mnt/boot-sav/sda7
/dev/sda8  fuseblk     25G   16G  8.5G  66% /mnt/boot-sav/sda8
/dev/sda9  fuseblk     30G   21G  9.1G  70% /mnt/boot-sav/sda9

=================== FDISK:

Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x255f86e3

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1          13      102400   de  Dell Utility
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2   *          13        1926    15360000    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3            1926       17105   121932488+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda4           17106       77825   487732535+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5           17106       39580   180530406    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda6           39581       45954    51199123+   7  HPFS/NTFS
Partition 6 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda7           45955       70815   199695951    7  HPFS/NTFS
Partition 7 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda8           70816       73996    25551351    7  HPFS/NTFS
Partition 8 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda9           73997       77825    30749696    7  HPFS/NTFS



=================== Before mainwindow
FSCK no PASTEBIN yes WUBI yes WINBOOT no
recommendedrepair, restore, QTY_OF_PART_FOR_REINSTAL 0
UNHIDEBOOT_ACTION yes (10s), noflag (sda3)
PART_TO_REINSTALL_GRUB , FORCE_GRUB  () REMOVABLEDISK
USE_SEPARATEBOOTPART  ()  (,  , )
UNCOMMENT_GFXMODE  ATA  ADD_KERNEL_OPTION  (acpi=off)
MBR_TO_RESTORE sda (mbr) (sda sda3)
internet: no-internet

=================== Actions
FSCK no PASTEBIN yes WUBI yes WINBOOT no
recommendedrepair, restore, QTY_OF_PART_FOR_REINSTAL 0
UNHIDEBOOT_ACTION yes (10s), noflag (sda3)
PART_TO_REINSTALL_GRUB , FORCE_GRUB  () REMOVABLEDISK
USE_SEPARATEBOOTPART  ()  (,  , )
UNCOMMENT_GFXMODE  ATA  ADD_KERNEL_OPTION  (acpi=off)
MBR_TO_RESTORE sda (mbr) (sda sda3)
mount -o loop /mnt/boot-sav/sda6/ubuntu/disks/root.disk /mnt/boot-sav/wubi1
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
Warning: unknown mime-type for "/mnt/boot-sav/wubi1/home" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no "view" mailcap rules found for type "application/octet-stream"
Will restore the MBR_TO_RESTORE : sda (mbr) into sda
dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
parted /dev/sda set 3 boot on


Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.

internet: no-internet
internet: connected
paste.debian ko, using paste.ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Run Boot-Repair's "Recommended repair". This will open a file
   browser that will let you access and backup your Ubuntu files if
   necessary.
2. Via Windows "Add/remove programs", remove your current Ubuntu
3. Reinstall Ubuntu OUTSIDE WIndows (without using Wubi), by following: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall